# DBI connection in BEGIN block and undefined values

Tags: perl, dbi

Following the guide [here](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=27128) I wanted to place a DBI connection handling subroutine in my `perl` code. I figured the `BEGIN` block was a reasonable place to put it so if I ever have an issue with the `DBI` connection it will fail prior to moving through the remaining (which is rather long).

```
BEGIN {
        my $dbh;
        use constant {
                my_host => 'database=MYDB;host=MYHOST',
                my_user => 'USER',
                my_pass => 'PASSWORD'
        };

        sub get_db_handle {
                unless (defined ($dbh)) {
                my $dbh = DBI->connect(
                                ('DBI:mysql:' . my_host),
                                my_user, my_pass,
                                {PrintError => 0, AutoCommit => 0}
                                ) or die $DBI::errstr;
        }
        return $dbh;
        }
}

...
        # Everything works fine without it being in the BEGIN
        my $db = get_db_handle();
        my $sth = $db->prepare($sql);
```

When run however I get the expected error:

> Can't call method "prepare" on an undefined value

To get around this I run the DBI connect string right after declaring the `use constant` values and it works, but this doesn't seem to be the best approach and the author did not have any additional information on this implementation posted.

Is there a typically usage illustrating this approach with creating the DBI handler and a sub to pass it around a script that I should look into, or is there a better approach to the `defined` statement that will allow me to use the above method?

Comment: Aside from the error you mentioned, I think you meant to actually try to connect in the BEGIN, but you didn't.

Comment: Yup connect during BEGIN, but using the get_db_handle if possible.

Comment: I don't see why you want to declare `get_db_handle` in a `BEGIN` block rather than just at the top of the file. The connect attempt is still made only when the subroutine is called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're declaring two variables named `$dbh`. Use `$dbh` instead of `my $dbh` to use an existing variable.

---

Also, you don't actually try to connect at compile-time as you want to do, and you forgot to check if `prepare` succeeded. Fixed:

```
use constant {
   MY_HOST => 'database=MYDB;host=MYHOST',
   MY_USER => 'USER',
   MY_PASS => 'PASSWORD',
};

{
   my $dbh;

   sub get_db_handle {
       $dbh ||= DBI->connect(
          'DBI:mysql:' . MY_HOST,
          MY_USER, MY_PASS,
          { PrintError => 0, AutoCommit => 0 },
       )
          or die $DBI::errstr;

       return $dbh;
   }
}

# Make sure DB errors are discovered early.
BEGIN { get_db_handle(); }

...

my $dbh = get_db_handle();
my $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql)
   or die $DBI::errstr;
```

---

If you use `RaiseError => 1`, this can be shortened to

```
use constant {
   MY_HOST => 'database=MYDB;host=MYHOST',
   MY_USER => 'USER',
   MY_PASS => 'PASSWORD',
};

{
   my $dbh;

   sub get_db_handle {
       return $dbh ||= DBI->connect(
          'DBI:mysql:' . MY_HOST,
          MY_USER, MY_PASS,
          { RaiseError => 1, PrintError => 0, AutoCommit => 0 },
       );
   }
}

# Make sure DB errors are discovered early.
BEGIN { get_db_handle(); }

...

my $dbh = get_db_handle();
my $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
```

Not sure how much sense it makes to cache a handle that has transactions enabled, though.

Answer (score 5):

Remove 2-nd `my $dbh`:

```
sub get_db_handle {
                unless (defined ($dbh)) {
                $dbh = DBI->connect(# <- no "my" here
                                ('DBI:mysql:' . my_host),
                                my_user, my_pass,
                                {PrintError => 0, AutoCommit => 0}
                                ) or die $DBI::errstr;
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you have declared *two* `$dbh` variables inside the `BEGIN` block.

The `unless` checks whether the *outer* `$dbh` has been defined and, if not, declares a new `$dbh`, assigns a database handle to it, and then throws it away.

The subroutine returns the value of the *outer* `$dbh`, which is always `undef`.

The solution is to remove the `my` from the beginning of the `connect` statement; then the same variable is being referred to everywhere.